# favicon.ico for the new logo suffers on dark backgrounds

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon

Coinciding with the name change back to Stack Overflow and the logo update ([nice video, by the way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1&v=uipTZ2re4Uk)), I noticed that the favicon.ico does not do well on dark backgrounds due to transparency issues.

Here's a picture of the new favicon between the old one and meta's.

[image: New logo on dark background]

I'm not sure if this a GTK rendering issue in Linux or more widespread.

Comment: Looks absolutely horrible on anything other than a white background.

Comment: It doesn't look well on IE11 either...Can someone hit the red button and take everything off-line so this can get fixed first?

Comment: The meta favicon has a bar too many now.

Comment: fix is building out, ETA ~4minutes

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure that's not by design?

Comment: a bar too far...

Comment: We're lowering our bars.

Comment: So many dupes…!

Comment: cool, now the meta favicon has the same problem. :)

Comment: @balpha: don't forget the careers favicon! It it using a white background all the way through..

Comment: @balpha That's why I love this place. I can complain about the most pointless, miniscule detail and you all jump to fix and deploy it before the answer-accept timeout even expires :)

Comment: _“Sorry I apparently missed my opportunity to capture the old one before it updated in my bookmarks bar”_ [There you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUW0X.png).

Comment: @Xufox Thanks. Added above.

Comment: @NathanTuggy my own wouldn't have been a dupe if the search function were picking up in real time. I checked before I posted.

Comment: Now the Meta Icon still has the issue.

Comment: P.S. What name change?

Comment: @MarkRansom http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/?cb=1

Comment: @balpha: status-almost-complete. Main site favicon is fixed, meta favicon still has some transparency issues.

Comment: It still seems like it has a very low resolution when compared to the previous incarnation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been corrected. The issue here was accidentally saving out the original PNG files as PNG-8s instead of PNG-24s. Lesson learned.

[image: FAVICONNNNNNNNSSSSSS]

--

**Edit:** *I am a Senior Product Designer at **Stack Overflow**.*

Comment: Still broken on chat...

Comment: Chat icons are building. Give it a few minutes.

Comment: The icon is still a *lot* different than the old one, is that intentional? In particular the box at the bottom is about half the height, and the bottom bars are more saturated instead of less saturated.

Comment: @Hynes At the first look it's so confusing if your write such an answer without a diamond next to your name. After looking into your profile I saw that you work for SE.

Comment: @Rizier123 Ah. Good point. Forgot that I didn't have a diamond here. I do on Meta.SE.

Comment: FWIW the meta one is pretty much invisible on a dark background

Comment: @Hynes Also since you are designer for SE, I think I have to say, that the new lighter orange (on the main site) is sooo creepy, since I have the feeling I can't see right anymore, since the previous orange was more colorful.

Comment: This appears to still be broken on chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @durron597 Give them 6-8 weeks to fix it, it won't take long :]

Comment: The problem still persists for chat.stackoverflow.com favicons.

Comment: @Hynes blog.stackoverflow.com still has the PNG-8 one

Answer (score 3):

Is it really fixed? It still looks bad in chats.

[image]

[image]