# Favicon for the new Stack Overflow logo?

Tags: bug, design, logo, favicon

**I like our new logo:**

[image: New StackOverflow Logo]

[image: Favicon-sized]

But is it just me, or does the lowest orange bar look way darker than the rest?

Maybe it should be rendered a bit lighter to compensate?  What does the design team think?

([This other post is related to export](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306142/2619939), mine is suggesting the rendering compensate for how the diagonal lines appear lighter (*blame the pixels*).)

Comment: I'm on the latest Chomium/Arch Linux.  This is just a screenshot, sized up in GIMP (without interpolation) to show the problem easier.

Comment: It's the same color, it's just that since the lowest bar is completely straight, it's not 'fuzzy' like the others.

Comment: BTW those of you on hi-DPI/Retina screens probably won't notice the problem.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't see any change in the Stack Overflow logo?

Comment: @D4V1D There is a difference- The logo used to be grey on the bottom bars and then go to orange. Now the stack is all orange.

Comment: @Kendra: You're right. And there used to be also 6 bars when there is only 5 now.

Comment: @D4V1D And the little "container" thing the bars are in is a bit shorter.

Comment: @SuperScript you could go as far as saying that "container thing" is some sort of "stack" holder, and it's contents are "overflowing". *IF* you wanted to go that far.

Comment: Just pinging this thread with the related (but different) question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306191/new-favicon-is-too-thin/306192