# New favicon is too thin

Tags: discussion, favicon

With the new Stack Overflow logo, there is also a new favicon. But it is very thin and missing a lot of contrast.

Here is the old favicon compared to the new one in my tab bar right now:

[image: Old vs. new favicon]

Of course, the old one isn’t too noticeable with my current color scheme on deactivated tabs either, but the new logo stands out in a bad way with that very light bar at the bottom.

Even selected it does not really stand out much and feels very thin:

[image: New favicon selected]

I don’t have any idea how to change this, but it doesn’t feel right right now.

In comparison, I think the meta icon has a good contrast so it works pretty well.

Comment: Btw. the [favion of chat](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WfGrV.png) is really bad.

Comment: Also the one for careers has a white background.

Comment: You're just not used to it, as with all UI changes. Give it a week at most and the old favicon will look too wide to you.

Answer (score 20):

I had a look into this last night.  The favicon for chat is [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=c8).  It has some rather bad alpha channel issues that means it looks awful against any non-white background.  I've been [alerted in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306191/new-favicon-is-too-thin/306192?noredirect=1#comment247983_306192) that the chat favicon issue has been already raised [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306142/favicon-ico-for-the-new-logo-suffers-on-dark-backgrounds) and it looks like the issue is that the favicon was saved using PNG-8 vs PNG-24.

The new main site favicon is [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d) and looks fairly OK against a range of greys, but does have the issue you allude to.  The old main site icon is [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=6cd6089ee7f6)

Against dark grey (`#444444`) backgrounds they look as follows (sorry the png's are slightly different sizes - manual job...):

#### New chat

[image: New chat site favicon against grey (#444444)]

#### New main

[image: New main site favicon against grey (#444444)]

#### Old main

[image: Old main site favicon against grey (#444444)]

I guess this is an artefact of the rebrand and SO are onto it...

To address more directly your original question - here's a comparison (at the same magnification) of old and new main site favicon)

[image: New vs old main site favicon]

I'm not sure the new one is "thinner" exactly, although it might be marginally.  It is, however, more squat and the grey is noticeably lighter.  I guess the thing is that the bars are all one color now - so if you "lose" one due to contrast issues, you lose them all - whereas before that was unlikely.  That doesn't explain the chat favicon though :)

---

***EDIT***:  For completeness - I found a tab with the old chat favicon still on it, and it resides [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=c7)

---

***Caveat:*** These renderings were all taken from Chrome browser.  However, I have installed a dark theme on firefox and the same visual appearance applies.

Comment: Regarding the messed up chat favicon, it's a further symptom [of this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306142/favicon-ico-for-the-new-logo-suffers-on-dark-backgrounds) and has been noted in comments there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - updated.

Comment: Meta is also practically invisible on a dark background now

Comment: They should make it white, then it would disappear on a white background :). I don't think you'll ever get a color that won't disappear on someone's screen.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'd take a gradient instead of the flat color. Should work (though look slightly different) on both. Or even just make the bottom box orange

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree, the gradient was better. It feels like we're taking a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: agree with you both to be honest.