# Main and meta site logos aren't the same size

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, logo

In the same vein as the recent discussion on [the favicon being too thin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306191/new-favicon-is-too-thin), I spotted a difference between main and meta with respect to logo size. Here are the two current sprite sources being discussed:

[image]
[image]

I am a bit to lazy to overlay these for comparison, but using the below script (unhide and run), you can more easily see the difference (hover on/off to toggle main to meta):

```js
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function() {
    $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
        new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
    }).hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-alt-src="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/img/sprites.svg" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg" width="240" height="500" />
```

Basically, the "overflow" icon and logo text are a bit larger overall, and certain wider on meta than on main, and to me the effect is a bit jarring when switching between the sites. Others may not notice at all, but if we're shooting for consistency between sites, especially after the recent rebranding, I thought I should point it out!

Expanding on my comment on the favorite star: zoom these SVGs up to 500% or so -- there's some odd construction there, too (it's better on meta's sprite).

Comment: I noticed this the first time while switching tabs between meta and SO. I thought it was my browser's problem. (I probably zoomed in in meta or something)

Comment: Comparing the actual SVG data, there are some very minute differences in the favorite stars as well.

Comment: I think SO is the only website where the slightest change in design suffers QA validation by hundreds of users.

Comment: I think SO is the only website where the dev/design team itself doesn't do any QA :P

Comment: The stack overflow meta logo is bigger than the SO logo. That's because it meta-overflows itself :D

Comment: This is such a good use of code snippets. +1.

Comment: Actually the logo is the same size; you're seeing an optical illusion because the stroke is thicker. The text is wider, though. My counter-question is ... so what? Why is this a problem?

Comment: Maybe I am obsessing over it a bit, though other sites in the network generally have identically sized and shaped logos aside from the "meta" indicator. Between different sites I don't see it as an issue, but between main and its meta, maybe the graphic design team would like to consolidate their assets here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, the “base” of the logo is about .4 pixels higher and .7 pixels wider for the meta logo. But yeah, the font difference is more noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the links, @poke. Looks like the favorite stars were fixed in the latest renditions, but the logo "issue" is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [rollout of the new top-bar navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update?cb=1), this is no longer relevant.