# Please improve SO logo kerning

Tags: feature-request, design, logo

This might appear to be a petty matter, but it bugs me every time I see it.

[SO logos](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) are well-balanced, however, when scaled down, the kerning is starting to hurt. Any chance we could use a version of the logo which is kerned specifically for smaller screen sizes?

[image]

(You need to click on the pic to see the actual screenshot).

My system is OSX 10.11.3, Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit).

Ok, this turned out to be subjective, so I'll fix that just for me by other means. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you had not mentioned it, i would never have noticed it .. Now it bothers me to .. THANKS

Comment: [I see what you did there](https://xkcd.com/1015/)

Comment: You must think the logo is beautiful if you take such notice of it :) I don't even see it anymore, I have only eyes for questions, questions and more questions.

Comment: You linked a PNG, it doesn't have kerning problems.  The main page's logo is write-once debug-everywhere SVG.  Works fine on my machine, you need to include your OS and browser version number.

Comment: @HansPassant: I updated the post.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Gimby same here, I only sort logos into two broad types.  Sufficiently small to be completely ignorable, and obnoxiously large wastes of space that generate a new rule in my adblocker to make go away.  SO's is the former.

Comment: @HansPassant It's common within design circles to create variations on a logo or wordmark that are tuned to look better at smaller sizes. The version you put on a building as a sign and the one that shows up on a business card are often different in subtle but important ways. Same principle applies here. One SVG cannot handle all cases.

Comment: I commonly spot and am bothered by bad kerning, but I must admit I'm having trouble spotting what you are trying to point out. What does your screenshot even portray? How is any of the sides "scaled down"? (They both look like the real page normally does in my browser without any scaling.) Is one of the sides supposed to be a "fixed version"? I mean, I can tell that they are different, but I don't understand the purpose of the differences.

Comment: @DTH: Good point, I'm going to stop looking for the problem in the hopes that I never notice it!

Comment: @tadman: that's correct.

Comment: @Dolda2000: the actual version is on the left, an improvement (one of many possible) on the right.

Comment: Really, I don't know what you're talking about. The left version is the one that looks correct to me. It is the most faithful to the original logo, the one you [link to on the corporate page](http://stackoverflow.com/company/logos). There isn't supposed to be that much space between "stack" and "overflow." The different weights provide adequate separation.

Comment: The keming looks fine to me.

Comment: @dennisdeems I think the difference is the space between *stack* and *overflow*.

Comment: Maybe a hand drawn arrow pointing to the extra space would make it easier for others to see where it is ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't it supposed to look like a stylized single-word-from-two-words? As in, separated by the font weight, stack**overflow**

Comment: The stylization is causing people to spell "Stack Overflow" other than as described in SO's branding guidelines.

Comment: That [+new tab] though :D

Comment: Do you prefer the [meta] logo? [I submitted a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306347/main-and-meta-site-logos-arent-the-same-size) a while back pointing out differences between the logos; meta is just slightly more spaced out than main.

Comment: An example of the difference the OP is trying to show is the spacing between the `s` and the `t` in `stack`, which is increased in his 'fixed' version on the right.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: yes, the meta logo looks better, I guess this is because there's not so much contrast between black letters and the white background: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qG1VB.png

Answer (score 7):

I overlay-ed the right portion of the screenshot over the top of the left. I'm assuming left was the original, but just to be safe I went and did a visual once over on the StackOverflow main site.

[image]

This might be very un-UX of me, and I'm no kerning expert.. but why is this even an "issue"? I would think that the current logo, should look exactly the same at all resolutions.

I'm not aware of (m)any companies that modify the word spacing of their logo at different sizes. EG: [Coke](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=coca%20cola&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirmZipoJLLAhVFWxoKHdNTDJcQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=coca%20cola%20official%20branding&imgrc=_), [Netflix](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=netflix%20branding&biw=1920&bih=909&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLtZiToZLLAhULtBoKHbLuCVMQ_AUIBygB), the list can go on and on.  The saying, if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it, comes to mind.