# Logos on SO and mSO are not aligned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, top-bar, logo

For some reason, the logos on [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) are not aligned.  They're off by 4 pixels.

[image: Stackoverflow Logo]

[SO](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) has this in the CSS:

```css
.so-header .-logo._glyph .-img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[mSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) has this:

```css
.so-header .-logo._glyph .-img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 185px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The `margin-top` causes the difference.

Comment: Related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306347/main-and-meta-site-logos-arent-the-same-size maybe?

Comment: @Stijn I checked, and they are the same.  Well, similar enough anyway.  It's the margin that causes the difference.

Comment: @Stijn https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=d689de80c4e2 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/img/sprites.svg?v=0dda4ff8cad9 if you're curious.

Comment: the fullsize version of the so logo seems to align properly

Comment: Why do you people keep pointing these things out!?!  You're driving me insane!

Comment: I just spat my coffee everywhere in disgust. Absolute outrage.

Comment: I will never use Stackoverflow again. These are the things that destroy the community. It shows that the company is run terribly badly. `-4px`! Outrageous. (/s)

Comment: I can't stop seeing this now... whhyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: Both sites are off by 0.1 microns.. IT'S DRIVING ME MAD! In all seriousness though, I think that this is hardly a top-priority issue.

Comment: @cybermonkey: It is now!!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to comments from reddit!

Comment: Literally unplayable.

Comment: You don't want to see what this looks like at 500% in chrome browser. Take my word for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

When we display full logo (glyph + label), we have to adjust its position to make it visually centered with navigation text next to it.

Reason: label "stack overflow" is not perfectly centered with glyph, that's why it looks a little bit off on areas where we don't have enough whitespace above and below AND when it's placed before other text (in this case navigation).

Comment: Judging from the comments, that explanation is hardly satisfactory for some people's OCD, but it makes sense.