# The favicon for the chat pages has not been fixed yet

Tags: bug, chat, favicon

I went onto chat today, and I noticed the favicon has not been fixed for it yet, it still has the white background

[image: SO chat favicon]

Compared to the favicon on the main page of SO

[image]

Comment: It looks like a new favicon to me. All those stacked rectangles seem to have the same color, which came with the logo change. So it seems like it's intentionally different.

Comment: I get your point, but what makes me think it is not, is that was what the main site favicon looked like before it was fixed. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306142/favicon-ico-for-the-new-logo-suffers-on-dark-backgrounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has apparently been fixed but the chance didn't go through probably due to cache. On Mac OS X I've fixed it by refreshing with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.