# Stack Overflow favicon looks bad on dark backgrounds

Tags: bug, favicon, blog

The Stack Overflow icon on the Stack Exchange blog looks *broken* on dark-themed backgrounds (example is from Chrome and has Google and Meta favicons as example):

[image: example favicon from Chrome]

Stack Overflow website too suffered from [the same broken favicon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306142/favicon-ico-for-the-new-logo-suffers-on-dark-backgrounds) a while back but that seems fixed now.

Perhaps this is the same issue on the blog's servers?

---

**Update:** It doesn't appear to be a caching issue:

[image: example re caching]

This is fetched from [blog.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico), with the cache disabled and it still shows transparency issues.

Comment: You must be being served an old version of the favicon. This was fixed a while back already.

Comment: @TinyGiant It doesn't appear to be a caching issue. Have updated the question with the evidence.

Comment: Yeah, but cloudflare can do some pretty funky things and all of sudden you're being served an old version of a file. I doubt that it has to do with your browser.

Comment: @TinyGiant True, I can see Cloudflare headers in the request. Can cloudflare be caching things for ~ 1 month after the original fix was deployed?

Comment: I could see it happening, weirder things have happened.

Comment: Solution: Stop being so dark ;)

Comment: @pnuts: Please, whats the point of pushing all these ancient questions to the front-page?